# Session in php query

Tags: php, session

Suppose i have a login page login.php and if a user logs in ,then he should be redirected to userpanel.php.How to make use of session on both pages such that only verified session user can see the second page and no one else can see that page.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: am not able to search it.what i did till now is i have started session on login.php and have used $_session['abc']=input from username textbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated above, set up the session in your login.php page. On successful login, we set up the session so the script knows.

**login.php**

```
session_start();
....
$_SESSION['loggedin'] == TRUE;
```

You should write a function that checks if the user is logged in, for the sake of simplicity and to avoid repeating yourself in every file.

**userpanel.php**

```
session_start();
requireLogin();

.. all the other stuff you want to do..
```

The function can be kept in a general file you include in each page, and can be as simple as:

```
function requireLogin(){
    if($_SESSION['loggedin'] !== TRUE){
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
}
```

although you could extend it to check for other levels of authentication; if the user is an admin, logged in, a moderator, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start a session in page one and set a variable (depending on db or authentication of some sort:

```
session_start();
...
// if authenticated, set this variable
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
```

Then in the second page check if the variable exists:

```
session_start()
if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == TRUE) {
   // Do stuff
} else {
   header("Location: http://example.com/login.php");
   exit();
}
```

Comment: thanx bro .i ll try and let u know